# Fit function returning TypeError : float() argument must be string or a number in ScikitLearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, anaconda

I am learning scikit learn to perform certain classifications. I am following the tutorial against my data set. When I run the script , I get a type error

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Description': pd.Categorical(["apple", "table", "red"]), 'Labels' : pd.Categorical(["Fruit","Furniture","Color"])})

counts = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(data['Description'].values)

tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(counts)
train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(tf_transformer)
```

Error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-97-9a649172d3b7>", line 10, in <module>
    train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(tf_transformer)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1005, in transform
    X = sp.csr_matrix(X, dtype=np.float64, copy=copy)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 69, in __init__
    self._set_self(self.__class__(coo_matrix(arg1, dtype=dtype)))
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 204, in __init__
    self.data = self.data.astype(dtype)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

I must be doing something really dumb because I dont fully understand the APIs. Can someone please tell me how to unblock myself?

Thanks.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to trace back to any line of code that you've written. You'll need to provide that mapping.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from this

```
tf_transformer.transform(tf_transformer)
```

I think this is wrong syntax `tf_transformer` is an object of `TfidfTransformer`. The function expects sparse matrix. Instead you could use `fit_transform` function

```
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit_transform(counts)
```